# Accuracy error in binomials using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, precision

The value is absolute integer, not a floating point to be doubted, also, it is not about an overflow since a double value can hold until 2^1024.

```
fprintf('%f',realmax)
179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The problem I am facing in `nchoosek` function that it doesn't produce exact values

```
fprintf('%f\n',nchoosek(55,24));
2488589544741302.000000
```

While it is a percentage error of 2 regarding that `binomian(n,m)=binomial(n-1,m)+binomial(n-1,m-1)` as follows

```
fprintf('%f',nchoosek(55-1,24)+nchoosek(55-1,24-1))
2488589544741301.000000
```

---

Ps: The exact value is `2488589544741300`

[this demo shows](http://ideone.com/E2VRGn)

What is wrong with MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the `realmax` function is wrong. It's the maximum value which can be stored, but with such large numbers you have a floating point precision error far above 1. The first integer which can not be stored in a double value is `2^53+1`, try `2^53==2^53+1` for a simple example.

If the symbolic toolbox is available, the easiest to implement solution is using it:

```
>> nchoosek(sym(55),sym(24))

ans =

2488589544741300
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between something that looks like an integer (`55`) and something that's actually an integer (in terms of variable type).

The way you're calculating it, your values are stored as floating point (which is what `realmax` is pointing you to - the largest positive floating point number - check  `intmax('int64')` for the largest possible integer value), so you can get floating point errors. An absolute difference of 2 in a large value is not that unexpected - the actual percentage error is tiny.

Plus, you're using `%f` in your format string - e.g. asking it to display as floating point.

For `nchoosek` specifically, from the docs, the output is returned as a nonnegative scalar value, of the same type as inputs n and k, or, if they are different types, of the non-double type (you can only have different input types if one is a double).

In Matlab, when you type a number directly into a function input, it generally defaults to a float. You have to force it to be an integer.

Try instead:

```
fprintf('%d\n',nchoosek(int64(55),int64(24)));
```

Note: `%d` not `%f`, converting both inputs to specifically integer. The output of `nchoosek` here should be of type `int64`.

Comment: thank you very much for the effort but [hope you check your codes before posting them](http://ideone.com/rP8kEG)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to MATLAB, but since you're obviously okay working with Octave I'll post my observations based on that.

If you look at the Octave source code using `edit nchoosek` or [here](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/95da3bc8a281/scripts/specfun/nchoosek.m) you'll see that the equation for calculating the binomial coefficient is quite simple:

```
A = round (prod ((v-k+1:v)./(1:k)));
```

As you can see, there are `k` divisions, each with the possibility of introducing some small error. The next line attempts to be helpful and warn you of the possibility of loss of precision:

```
if (A*2*k*eps >= 0.5)
  warning ("nchoosek", "nchoosek: possible loss of precision");
```

So, if I may slightly modify your final question, what is wrong with Octave? I would say nothing is wrong. The authors obviously knew of the possibility of imprecision and included a check to warn users when that possibility arises. So the function is working as intended. If you require greater precision for your application than the built-in function provides, it looks as though you'll need to code (or find) something that calculates the intermediate results with greater precision.